# Ranges múltiplas no Excel com vb.net

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Estou a tentar definir uma range no vb.net para escrever dados nos campos assinalados a azul:

[image]

Eu tentei usar este código que encontrei nas páginas de ajuda da Microsoft, mas acho que se destina ao VBA apenas:

```
Sub ClearRanges() 
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:D9,G9:H16,B14:D18").ClearContents 
End Sub
```

O meu atual código é este:

```
Dim appXL As Excel.Application
Dim wbXL As Excel.Workbook
Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
Dim raXL As Excel.Range

Try
   ' Open workbook.
   wbXL = appXL.Workbooks.Open(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\test.xltx")
   shXL = wbXL.ActiveSheet

   ' Define Range.
   shXL.Range("A2:E2,A5:E5,A8:E8,A11:E11,A14:E14,A17:E17,A20:E20,A23:E23,A26:E26,A29:E29,A32:E32,A35:E35,A38:E38").Value = "TEST"
Catch ex As Exception
   MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message)
   appXL.Quit()
End Try
```

Comment: Por favor, traduza a sua pergunta.

Comment: Peço desculpa, já esta.

Comment: O conteúdo não é escrito na planilha?